# Looping through and filtering the data in express and mongoose

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I have a backend with Node.js, Express and Mongoose. I am trying to filter an array of documents that is nested deep in an object but I am not able to access the array for some reason. The route `req` has an attached document of the user who is logged in. Below is mycode.

```
router.post("/users/:id/accept", auth, async (req, res) => { 
  try {
    // this filter is not working
    await req.user.friendRequests.filter((usr) => usr.owner !== req.params.id);
    await req.user.save();
    res.send("Accepted")
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
  }
});
```

If I `console.log(req.user)` I get:

```
{
  dateOfBirth: { date: 28, month: 'Sep', year: 2002 },
  gender: 'male',
  cover: null,
  _id: 5f71c0674a54b03e70fcbe97,
  firstName: 'jake',
  lastName: 'sulli',
  email: 'hello2@gmail.com',
  friendRequests: [
      _id: 5f71c1184a54b03e70fcbea0,
      owner: '5f71c0d14a54b03e70fcbe9b',
      friend: false,
      name: 'mad max'
    },
    {
      _id: 5f76a7872b21c8208f3caa5f,
      owner: '5f742182931ab9125bc2ec9d',
      friend: false,
      name: 'shriya rai'
    },
    {
      _id: 5f76f6fa85e74758e76cb1ec,
      owner: '5f76f541ab7a1255dc78987d',
      friend: false,
      name: 'dara singh'
    }
  ],
}
```

I am not able to get the `friendRequests` array if I `console.log()` but I can get `name`, `email`, and `gender`.  What I want to achieve is, if the `friendRequests.owner === req.params.id` then I want to remove that object from the array.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issue with your `friendRequests` array.

First you didn't begin or end your object correctly.

```
friendRequests: [ 
    {        <=========================== Need another bracket 
      _id: 5f71c1184a54b03e70fcbea0,
      owner: '5f71c0d14a54b03e70fcbe9b',
      friend: false,
      name: 'mad max'
    },
    {
      _id: 5f76a7872b21c8208f3caa5f,
      owner: '5f742182931ab9125bc2ec9d',
      friend: false,
      name: 'shriya rai'
    },
    {
      _id: 5f76f6fa85e74758e76cb1ec,
      owner: '5f76f541ab7a1255dc78987d',
      friend: false,
      name: 'dara singh'
    }
  ]
```

Second make sure you make those _id into string

```
5f76f6fa85e74758e76cb1ec to "5f76f6fa85e74758e76cb1ec"
```

Comment: I might have removed the bracket while adding question as there were other data as well like tokens array etc. The question was how can i access the **friendRequests array** inside the route so that that i can remove the object  that matches the **req.params.id** .because currently if i **console.log(req.user.friendRequests)** it gives **undefined**